# How do applications handle ports if they are not open?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am trying to write an application in c++ using winsock.
I need to handle a case where default port used by the app is not open to use then what is fallback mechanism?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That completely depends on you.

There is a mechanism called port knocking: The application just tries a range of ports until it finds one it can bind to. Obviously server AND client have to do this to find each other if the default port did not work out.

You could also just display an error message and let the user decide on how to deal with this.

Or you specify a fallback port in a config file...
Just to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks I shall try this method.

Comment: If you do this, you need to inform the client which port the server has bound to, otherwise the client could connect to any application.

Answer (score 1):

Server or client?

In the server, if the requested port is already taken, you log an error and stop. This is why ports are often stored in configuration.

For the client, if you cannot connect to the specified port, you log an error too. Its not much different from not being able to connect to any other network resource, like a URL in your browser.

Comment: Ok. So in case of windows, I use Outlook, steam client, do they always get required port on my system? I didn't encounter a case where any app on my system shouted for not being able to open a port.

Comment: Yes outlook and steam will have different ports, but there shall be some default port for outlook, steam etc. Do they use port knocking like feature?

Comment: Yes, they use different ports, the defaults are different. Just like web servers run on port 80 and 443, and telnet on port 25, these are well-defined (or well known) ports. If you star a different program that uses the default port Exchange uses, it'll simply fail to run and report an error. Often you can change iot in configuration but then its up to you to tell all clients what the new port to connect to is.